# Shared isolated storage between Silverlight application and standalone application

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-7, .net-4.0, isolatedstorage

Is it possible to share an isolated storage between a Silverlight application and a standalone application (possibly deployed with ClickOnce technology)?

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dzh4ws(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with an OOB elevated trust app in Silverlight.

The Silverlight app can write the location of its Isolated Storage to the Registry (using COM automation) which your other app can then locate. I'm not sure if you will be able to write to the IS, but you can certainly read from it in the other app.

More on COM automation in Silverlight:
http://justinangel.net/CuttingEdgeSilverlight4ComFeatures